# Bigquery sql: Replace keys of json to a new values present in a column

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I have two tables in Big Query as shown: table_1 has id, properties in json format, collection columns repectively.

table_2 has collection, property_key, property_name columns

I want to replace the json keys in properties column from table_1 with property_name from table_2

condition: where tabe_1.collection = table_2.collection and also property_key in table_2 contains the actual json_key's

Table_1:

| id | properties | collection |
| --- | --- | --- |
| workflow:623a776f04f1527a7bc2b3ed | {"counterpartyName_string":{"type":"string","value":"XYZ"},"signerc_string":{"type":"string","value":"xyz_a"},"signer3_email":{"type":"email","value":"cyz@gmail.com"},"custome54_string":{"type":"string","value":"No (default answer)"},"paperSource_string":{"type":"string","value":"Our paper"},"acceptanceType_string":{"type":"string","value":"eSignature"},"agreementDate":{"type":"date","value":"2018-04-02"},"workflowId":{"type":"string","value":"123"},"workflowCreatedDate":{"type":"date","value":"2018-03-23"},"workflowUpdatedDate":{"type":"date","value":"2022-04-02T15:16:24.688Z"},"workflowCreator":{"type":"string","value":"6008"},"workflowOwner":{"type":"string","value":"6008"},"workflowConfigurationVersionNumber":{"type":"number","value":12.0}} | 57b4c959e899aa130069e4e0 |
| 52523e7b-0a19-4551-be43-5c1d124beea0 | {"amendment":{"type":"boolean","value":false},"10vs25term":{"type":"string","value":"10 Term"},"counterpartyAddress":{"type":"string","value":"USA"},"agreementDate":{"type":"date","value":"2018-11-05"},"contractType":{"type":"string","value":"ABC"},"contactForNotice":{"type":"string","value":"UMC"},"statementOfWork":{"type":"boolean","value":false},"mastercardEntity":{"type":"string","value":"Master"},"folder":{"type":"string","value":"NDA"},"importBatch":{"type":"string","value":"Sale"},"counterpartyName":{"type":"string","value":"Gra"},"documentID":{"type":"string","value":"115"},"region":{"type":"string","value":"United States"},"effectiveDate":{"type":"date","value":"2018-11-05"}} | 5db09e5d9c32aaa121bf4ca1 |

Table_2:

| collection | property_key | property_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 57b4c959e899aa130069e4e0 | counterpartyName_string | Counterparty Name |
| 57b4c959e899aa130069e4e0 | signerc_string | Counterparty Signer Name |
| 57b4c959e899aa130069e4e0 | signer3_email | Counterparty Signer Email |
| 57b4c959e899aa130069e4e0 | custome54_string | Equipment |
| 5db09e5d9c32aaa121bf4ca1 | amendment | Amendment |
| 5db09e5d9c32aaa121bf4ca1 | 10vs25term | 10 vs 25 Term |
| 5db09e5d9c32aaa121bf4ca1 | counterpartyAddress | Counterparty Address |
| 5db09e5d9c32aaa121bf4ca1 | agreementDate | Agreement Date |

I wanted the result table be like a new column with changed properties field from table_1 as shown

Result_table:

| id | properties | collection | renamed_properties |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| workflow:623a776f04f1527a7bc2b3ed | {"counterpartyName_string":{"type":"string","value":"XYZ"},"signerc_string":{"type":"string","value":"xyz_a"},"signer3_email":{"type":"email","value":"cyz@gmail.com"},"custome54_string":{"type":"string","value":"No (default answer)"},"paperSource_string":{"type":"string","value":"Our paper"},"acceptanceType_string":{"type":"string","value":"eSignature"},"agreementDate":{"type":"date","value":"2018-04-02"},"workflowId":{"type":"string","value":"123"},"workflowCreatedDate":{"type":"date","value":"2018-03-23"},"workflowUpdatedDate":{"type":"date","value":"2022-04-02T15:16:24.688Z"},"workflowCreator":{"type":"string","value":"6008"},"workflowOwner":{"type":"string","value":"6008"},"workflowConfigurationVersionNumber":{"type":"number","value":12.0}} | 57b4c959e899aa130069e4e0 | {"Counterparty Name":{"type":"string","value":"XYZ"},"Counterparty Signer Name":{"type":"string","value":"xyz_a"},"Counterparty Signer Email":{"type":"email","value":"cyz@gmail.com"},"Equipment":{"type":"string","value":"No (default answer)"},"Paper Source":{"type":"string","value":"Our paper"},"Acceptance Type":{"type":"string","value":"eSignature"},"Agreement Date":{"type":"date","value":"2018-04-02"},"Workflow Id":{"type":"string","value":"123"},"Workflow Created Date":{"type":"date","value":"2018-03-23"},"Workflow Updated Date":{"type":"date","value":"2022-04-02T15:16:24.688Z"},"Workflow Creator":{"type":"string","value":"6008"},"Workflow Owner":{"type":"string","value":"6008"},"Workflow Configuration Version Number":{"type":"number","value":12.0}} |
| 52523e7b-0a19-4551-be43-5c1d124beea0 | {"amendment":{"type":"boolean","value":false},"10vs25term":{"type":"string","value":"10 Term"},"counterpartyAddress":{"type":"string","value":"USA"},"agreementDate":{"type":"date","value":"2018-11-05"},"contractType":{"type":"string","value":"ABC"},"contactForNotice":{"type":"string","value":"UMC"},"statementOfWork":{"type":"boolean","value":false},"mastercardEntity":{"type":"string","value":"Master"},"folder":{"type":"string","value":"NDA"},"importBatch":{"type":"string","value":"Sale"},"counterpartyName":{"type":"string","value":"Gra"},"documentID":{"type":"string","value":"115"},"region":{"type":"string","value":"United States"},"effectiveDate":{"type":"date","value":"2018-11-05"}} | 5db09e5d9c32aaa121bf4ca1 | {"Amendment":{"type":"boolean","value":false},"10 vs 25 Term":{"type":"string","value":"10 Term"},"Counterparty Address":{"type":"string","value":"USA"},"Agreement Date":{"type":"date","value":"2018-11-05"},"Contract Type":{"type":"string","value":"ABC"},"Contact For Notice":{"type":"string","value":"UMC"},"Statement Of Work":{"type":"boolean","value":false},"Mastercard Entity":{"type":"string","value":"Master"},"Folder":{"type":"string","value":"NDA"},"Import Batch":{"type":"string","value":"Sale"},"Counterparty Name":{"type":"string","value":"Gra"},"Document ID":{"type":"string","value":"115"},"Region":{"type":"string","value":"United States"},"Effective Date":{"type":"date","value":"2018-11-05"}} |

Can someone guide me the correct way to solve this in BigQuery using sql or sqludf's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select id, collection, 
  '{' || string_agg(renamed_property, ',' order by offset) || '}' renamed_properties
from (
  select id, collection, property, offset, 
    array_agg(replace(property, property_key, property_name) order by regexp_contains(property, property_key) desc limit 1)[offset(0)] renamed_property
  from table_1 t1,
  unnest(regexp_extract_all(properties, r'"[^"]+":{"type":"[^"]+","value":[^}]+}')) as property with offset 
  left join table_2 t2
  using (collection) 
  group by id, collection, property, offset
)
group by id, collection
```

if applied to sample data in y our question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, this query is working great but what if I have large amount of records in table 1, Is there a way to achieve parallelism in BigQuery?

Comment: Hi @R7777777, since you mentioned in your comment that Mikhail's answer is working, you may accept/upvote his posted answer. For your new inquiry, I suggest you post it as a new question since it is already related to optimizing a query request for a large table.

Comment: Which exactly key from your sample data was not renamed?

Comment: ok, I misread my sample dataset! this is super helpful. Thanks Mikhail

Comment: Hi @MikhailBerlyant - This part 
`properties, r'"[^"]+":{"type":"[^"]+","value":[^}]+}')` in regex works if we have type and value but what if some of json data has 
`key_123:{"type":"monetary_amount","value":{"amount":123.0,"currency":"USD"}}`, it doesn't give the expected output. can you please help?

Comment: @R7777777 - answer given for sample data in your question. if you have new or follow-up question - please post it as new - with all relevant details and data samples - and I will be happy to help further :o)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar json structure where, for each row, deep in a nested dictionary was a one key followed by a list of floats `..."Desine12": [5.223452345,2.23452345,6.456346,....],...` I needed to replace the first float. I used the regexp concept of "\2" which stores all of the string group that was to the right of the expression found, I also made the decision that I only cared about the first 8 digits of the float, so in the above it could go to ..."Desine": [x.xxxxxxx45,2.23452345,6.456346,....],...

The first step was to create the replacement string for each row:
`CONCAT("Desine12", '"', ': [',LEFT(CAST( MAX(Desine_element)-MIN(Desine_element) AS STRING), 8), "\\2") AS new_desine`

where I make a point to only keep 8 digits of the new float, which now looks like `"Desine12": [9.876543\2`

After that regexp_replace can go to work.
`REGEXP_REPLACE(Data, r'(Desine12": \[.{8})(.*)', new_desine) As NewData`

I didnt have to consider the possibility of finding a float with fewer than 8 digits, but presumably there would be a slightly different regexp for that (maybe find that first "[" after the key and then find the next comma after that).

Kind of a hack, but might be useful in some more obscure "json_modify" requests.

Comment: Incidentally, before doing the above I asked ChatGPT. She came up with a very elegant solution using the BigQuery JSON_MODIFY command, which turned out to have been a complete hallucination. I asked her if she was sure, ChatGPT apologized and came up with another almost equally elegant solution using JSON_REPLACE. Which was also a hallucination... Then again, Google developers, maybe ChatGPT was right and we do need such a BigQuery function....