# Replace/modify json keys and generate new json to a different column to existing record

Tags: json, string, google-bigquery

Little different to earlier ask: how to target and replace only JSON keys.

I have two tables in Big Query as shown: table_1 has id, properties in JSON format, collection columns respectively.

table_2 has collection, property_key, property_name columns

I want to replace the json keys in properties column from table_1 with property_name from table_2

condition: where tabe_1.collection = table_2.collection and also property_key in table_2 contains the actual json_key's

Table_1:

| id | collection | properties |
| --- | --- | --- |
| workflow:623a776f04f1527a7bc2b3ed | 57b4c959e899aa130069e4e0 | {"counterpartyName_2bc90766-6e76-4925-9287-60f1ee359613_string":{"type":"string","value":"XYZ"},"signerc_string":{"type":"string","value":"xyz_a"},"signer3_email":{"type":"email","value":"cyz@gmail.com"},"custome54_string":{"type":"string","value":"No (default answer)"}, "key_123":{"type":"monetary_amount","value":{"amount":123.0,"currency":"USD"}}} |
| 52523e7b-0a19-4551-be43-5c1d124beea0 | 5db09e5d9c32aaa121bf4ca1 | {"amendment":{"type":"boolean","value":false},"10vs25term":{"type":"string","value":"10 Term"},"key_123":{"type":"monetary_amount","value":{"amount":123.0,"currency":"USD"}}, "key_254":{"type":"total_amount","value":{"amount":123.0,"currency":"USD"}}} |

Table_2:

| collection | property_key | property_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 57b4c959e899aa130069e4e0 | counterpartyName_2bc90766-6e76-4925-9287-60f1ee359613_string | Counterparty Name |
| 57b4c959e899aa130069e4e0 | signerc_string | Counterparty Signer Name |
| 57b4c959e899aa130069e4e0 | signer3_email | Counterparty Signer Email |
| 57b4c959e899aa130069e4e0 | custome54_string | Equipment |
| 57b4c959e899aa130069e4e0 | key_123 | Amount |
| 5db09e5d9c32aaa121bf4ca1 | amendment | Amendment |
| 5db09e5d9c32aaa121bf4ca1 | 10vs25term | 10 vs 25 Term |
| 5db09e5d9c32aaa121bf4ca1 | counterpartyAddress | Counterparty Address |
| 5db09e5d9c32aaa121bf4ca1 | key_123 | Amount |
| 5db09e5d9c32aaa121bf4ca1 | key_254 | Total Amount |

I wanted the result table be like a new column with changed properties field from table_1 as shown

Result_table:

| id | old_properties | collection | new_properties |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| workflow:623a776f04f1527a7bc2b3ed | {"counterpartyName_2bc90766-6e76-4925-9287-60f1ee359613_string":{"type":"string","value":"XYZ"},"signerc_string":{"type":"string","value":"xyz_a"},"signer3_email":{"type":"email","value":"cyz@gmail.com"},"custome54_string":{"type":"string","value":"No (default answer)"},"key_123":{"type":"monetary_amount","value":{"amount":123.0,"currency":"USD"}}} | 57b4c959e899aa130069e4e0 | {"Counterparty Name":{"type":"string","value":"XYZ"},"Counterparty Signer Name":{"type":"string","value":"xyz_a"},"Counterparty Signer Email":{"type":"email","value":"cyz@gmail.com"},"Equipment":{"type":"string","value":"No (default answer)"},"Amount":{"type":"monetary_amount","value":{"amount":123.0,"currency":"USD"}}} |
| 52523e7b-0a19-4551-be43-5c1d124beea0 | {"amendment":{"type":"boolean","value":false},"10vs25term":{"type":"string","value":"10 Term"},"key_123":{"type":"monetary_amount","value":{"amount":123.0,"currency":"USD"}}, "key_254":{"type":"total_amount","value":{"amount":123.0,"currency":"USD"}}} | 5db09e5d9c32aaa121bf4ca1 | {"Amendment":{"type":"boolean","value":false},"10 vs 25 Term":{"type":"string","value":"10 Term"},"Amount":{"type":"monetary_amount","value":{"amount":123.0,"currency":"USD"}},"Total Amount":{"type":"total_amount","value":{"amount":123.0,"currency":"USD"}}} |

I am able to get to the part till mapping extent but I am struggling to replace the keys into respective json, this is the code I am currently using

```
select id, collection, 
  '{' || string_agg(renamed_property, ',' order by offset) || '}' renamed_properties
from (
  select id, collection, property, offset, 
    array_agg(replace(property, property_key, property_name) order by regexp_contains(property, property_key) desc limit 1)[offset(0)] renamed_property
  from table_1 t1,
  unnest(regexp_extract_all(properties, r'"[^"]+":{"type":"[^"]+","value":[^}]+}')) as property with offset 
  left join table_2 t2
  using (collection) 
  group by id, collection, property, offset
)
group by id, collection
```

This query is missing a '}' for every amount present in the properties field

Can someone guide me a better way to solve this in BigQuery using sql or sqludf's (assuming the data is huge)

Comment: can you clarify - what exactly difference between this and your previous similar question! please be very specific so it will help us to help you

Comment: previous one: has {key: type, value} in straight values. 
current one: has {key:type, value: {{}} } for example: if you see the properties in last field it has ```"key_254":{"type":"total_amount","value":{"amount":123.0,"currency":"USD"}} ```

In previous one we hard coded the part in regex ```r'"[^"]+":{"type":"[^"]+","value":[^}]+}'``` and it doesn't work in here because inside value there are multiple fields. How do we target and replace only the json_keys? Let me know if this clarifies?

Comment: @R7777777 The [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71756143) provided in the previous question is working as expected for this question too.

Comment: I just edited/trimmed properties to make it look simple. The value of the key is replacing as per expected but the part in the amount especially this one value:{"amount":123.0,"currency":"USD"} is having trouble, I think it is missing a '}'

Comment: If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Comment: Could you clarify what your requirements are?

Comment: Sure, given this json in properties field `{"amendment":{"type":"boolean","value":false},"key_123":{"type":"monetary_amount","value":{"amount":123.0,"currency":"USD"}}, "key_254":{"type":"total_amount","value":{"amount":123.0,"currency":"USD"}},"10vs25term":{"type":"string","value":"10 Term"}}` I wanted to change the respective json_keys and return as json string in new column in bigquery-sql

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you can try the code below.

```
SELECT id,collection,
 '{' || STRING_AGG(renamed_property, ','
 ORDER BY OFFSET ) || '}' renamed_properties
FROM (SELECT id,collection,property,
 OFFSET,
   ARRAY_AGG(REPLACE(property, property_key, property_name)
   ORDER BY REGEXP_CONTAINS(property, property_key) DESC
   LIMIT 1)[
 OFFSET (0)] renamed_property
 FROM `project.dataset.table1` t1,
   UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(properties, r'"[^"]+":{"type":"[^"]+","value":[^}]*.}')) AS property
 WITH OFFSET
 LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table2` t2
 USING(collection)
 GROUP BY id,collection,property,
 OFFSET)
GROUP BY id,collection
```

**Output Table**

[image]

Comment: The answer you provided works for this one after trimming the properties field and `amount` is present at the very end of properties. What if the amount field gets in between then I am getting an extra `}` in the end. try on this one for ex: `{"amendment":{"type":"boolean","value":false},"key_123":{"type":"monetary_amount","value":{"amount":123.0,"currency":"USD"}}, "key_254":{"type":"total_amount","value":{"amount":123.0,"currency":"USD"}},"10vs25term":{"type":"string","value":"10 Term"}}`